# How to write a function of type ('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b -> 'b

Tags: sml, fold

I'm new to Standard ML. I know that

```
fun foldr f [] a = a 
  | foldr f (x::xs) a = f x (foldr f xs a)

type = ('a -> 'b -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b -> 'b
```

How can I modify to change the type to ('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b -> 'b?

Answer (score 1):

The function you've written works great, but it assumes that `f` is a *curried* function taking two arguments. The type signature you're looking for indicates you want `f` to be a function which takes a single argument: a tuple.

The change is trivial. Simply change how you *call* `f`.

```
fun foldr _ [] a = a
  | foldr f (x::xs) a = f(x, (foldr f xs a));
```

Type signature:

```
('a * 'b → 'b) → 'a list → 'b → 'b
```